# Django search bar implementation with multiple field filtering

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement the functionality of a search bar.

my `models.py`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    groupId = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    questionTitle = models.TextField()
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    correctAnsRef = models.ManyToManyField(CorrectAns, related_name="questionReletedResponses")
```

My database is huge, so I tried to skip `Question.objects.all()` to save time.

my `views.py`:

```
def questionList(request)
# Searching Any Value
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST['searchKey'] != '':
        searchKey = request.POST['searchKey']
        questions = Question.objects.filter(questionId=searchKey)

    return render(request,'diagnosis/questionList.html', {'questions': questions})
```

This works perfectly but it can only filter by `questionId`. I wish to have such a search bar that will filter by matching all the fields(`questionId`, `groupId`, `questionTitle`... etc all) the `Question` model has. (note: `request.GET` already been used for pagination.)

Please suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Q Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for more complex lookups.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def questionList(request)
# Searching Any Value
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST['searchKey'] != '':
        searchKey = request.POST['searchKey']
        try:
            # tries to convert key into int
            searchKey = int(searchKey)

            # returns a Queryset with Question objects where any of the fields match the searchKey
            questions = Question.objects.filter(Q(questionId=searchKey) | Q(groupId=searchKey))
        except:
            # if key is not a number, don't query integer fields
            questions = Question.objects.filter(questionTitle=searchKey)

    return render(request,'diagnosis/questionList.html', {'questions': questions})
```

Comment: I already tried this. when I search with `height` it says `Field 'questionId' expected a number but got 'height'.`

Comment: @KanchonGharami: If the questionId field is an integer field, you need to convert the key from string to integer first. The exact details of how to handle the different fields will depend on your application. I've updated the answer with an example of how to handle search keys that are numbers vs search keys that are not numbers.

Comment: still it unable to find anything by searching with `height`. but there is one entry contains `height `